# Broken pipe sending chunks of data to chrome only streaming mp4 via range requests

Tags: java, google-chrome, http, video-streaming

I have an app where we serve resources protected by a custom authentication and authorization framework. This results in us having to respect range headers (in particular for video).

We had to change this code to support iOS and safari. In the process we started getting a broken pipe exception from Chrome but I can't figure out why. The video plays in chrome, safari and iOS as expected but we'd like to clean up the exception.

Chrome requests the whole package in the first request and we send it. Then it comes back and starts asking for chunks (see VID requests in image below.

What would cause chrome to kill this connection? Is it because there is something wrong with the first response returning the whole asset?

I've also tried returning a 200 when the first package sends everything but the outcome is the same.

No exceptions when using Safari.

Finally, we have other unprotected content served by EAP and no exceptions are reported.

The code that manages the response is:

```
protected void createResponse(HttpServletResponse resp, ResourceInterface resource,
                              ResourceInstance instance, String range) throws IOException, ServletException {

    _logger.info("Range parameter {}", range);
    int rangeStart = 0;
    int rangeEnd = -1;
    InputStream is = resource.getResourceStream(instance);
    int lengthHeader = is.available();
    if (range != null) {
        String[] rangeSplit = range.split("=");
        //String type = rangeSplit[0];
        String[] rangeVals = rangeSplit[1].split("-");
        rangeStart = Integer.parseInt(rangeVals[0]);
        resp.setHeader(HttpHeaders.ACCEPT_RANGES, "bytes");
        resp.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_PARTIAL_CONTENT);
        if (rangeVals.length > 1 && !StringUtils.isBlank(rangeVals[1])) {
            rangeEnd = Integer.parseInt(rangeVals[1]);
            //bufferSize = rangeEnd - rangeStart + 1;
        } else {
            rangeEnd = lengthHeader-1;
        }
        _logger.info("Start Range {} - End Range {}", rangeStart, rangeEnd);

        if (null != is) {
            resp.setHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_RANGE, "bytes " + rangeStart+"-"+rangeEnd + "/" + lengthHeader);
            String lastModifiedPattern = "EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss zzz";
            String dateString = DateConverter.getFormattedDate(new Date(), lastModifiedPattern);
            resp.setHeader(HttpHeaders.LAST_MODIFIED, dateString);
            _logger.info("serving resource {} with length {} bytes", instance.getFileName(), lengthHeader);
        }
    } else {
        _logger.info("NULL RANGE");
    }

    resp.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=" + instance.getFileName());
    resp.setContentType(instance.getMimeType());

    //CDP_DW_PUB-279: modifica nome file originale risorse protected
    String fileName = resource.getMasterFileName();
    if ("Image".equals(resource.getType())) {
        int lastIndexOf = instance.getFileName().lastIndexOf("_");
        String suffix = instance.getFileName().substring(lastIndexOf + 1, lastIndexOf + 3);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(suffix);
        sb.append("_");
        sb.append(fileName);
        fileName = sb.toString();
    }

    //CDP_DW_PUB-279


    ServletOutputStream out = resp.getOutputStream();
    try {
        is.skip(rangeStart);
        byte[] slice = new byte[rangeEnd-rangeStart+1];
        is.read(slice, 0, rangeEnd-rangeStart+1);
        resp.setHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_LENGTH, String.valueOf(slice.length));
        _logger.info("Slice size "+slice.length);
        out.write(slice);
    } catch (Throwable t) {
        _logger.error("Error extracting protected resource", t);
        throw new ServletException("Error extracting protected resource", t);
    } finally {
        out.close();
    }
}
```

The exception is pretty generic:

```
    Caused by: javax.servlet.ServletException: Error extracting protected resource
    at org.entando.entando.plugins.jacms.aps.servlet.ProtectedResourceProvider.createResponse(ProtectedResourceProvider.java:192)
    at org.entando.entando.plugins.jacms.aps.servlet.ProtectedResourceProvider.provideProtectedResource(ProtectedResourceProvider.java:112)
    ... 69 more
Caused by: org.eclipse.jetty.io.EofException
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint.flush(ChannelEndPoint.java:292)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.WriteFlusher.flush(WriteFlusher.java:429)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.WriteFlusher.completeWrite(WriteFlusher.java:384)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint$3.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:139)
    ... 7 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Broken pipe
    at sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcherImpl.write0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.write(SocketDispatcher.java:47)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.writeFromNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:93)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.write(IOUtil.java:65)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.write(SocketChannelImpl.java:471)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint.flush(ChannelEndPoint.java:270)
    ... 10 more
```

This is the network traffic. The VID calls are the calls for the MP4

[image: This is the network traffic]

The response headers are:

```
HTTP/1.1 206 Partial Content
Date: Thu, 08 Aug 2019 07:47:10 GMT
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, Authorization
Access-Control-Max-Age: 3600
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Last-Modified: Thu, 08 Aug 2019 09:47:10 CEST
Content-Disposition: inline; filename=38012166d7833c09c4b8632ea186634e.mp4

HTTP/1.1 206 Partial Content
Date: Thu, 08 Aug 2019 07:47:10 GMT
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, Authorization
Access-Control-Max-Age: 3600
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Last-Modified: Thu, 08 Aug 2019 09:47:10 CEST
Content-Disposition: inline; filename=38012166d7833c09c4b8632ea186634e.mp4
Content-Type: video/mp4;charset=utf-8
Server: Jetty(9.4.8.v20180619)
Content-Range: bytes 2097152-2107841/2107842
Content-Length: 10690
Content-Type: video/mp4;charset=utf-8
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Pragma: no-cache
Expires: 0
Server: Jetty(9.4.8.v20180619)
Content-Range: bytes 0-2107841/2107842
Content-Length: 2107842

HTTP/1.1 206 Partial Content
Date: Thu, 08 Aug 2019 07:47:10 GMT
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, Authorization
Access-Control-Max-Age: 3600
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Last-Modified: Thu, 08 Aug 2019 09:47:10 CEST
Content-Disposition: inline; filename=38012166d7833c09c4b8632ea186634e.mp4
Content-Type: video/mp4;charset=utf-8
Server: Jetty(9.4.8.v20180619)
Content-Range: bytes 2097152-2107841/2107842
Content-Length: 10690

HTTP/1.1 206 Partial Content
Date: Thu, 08 Aug 2019 07:47:10 GMT
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, Authorization
Access-Control-Max-Age: 3600
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Last-Modified: Thu, 08 Aug 2019 09:47:10 CEST
Content-Disposition: inline; filename=38012166d7833c09c4b8632ea186634e.mp4
Content-Type: video/mp4;charset=utf-8
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Pragma: no-cache
Expires: 0
Server: Jetty(9.4.8.v20180619)
Content-Range: bytes 65536-2107841/2107842
Content-Length: 2042306
```

Comment: Did you solve the problem? I'm with the same exception. In Firefox works great but in Chrome not.

Comment: @korima Yeah sort of. Never did figure out exactly what was wrong but the code below works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This ultimately resolved the issue.

```
protected void createResponse(HttpServletResponse resp, ResourceInterface resource,
            ResourceInstance instance) throws IOException, ServletException {
        resp.setContentType(instance.getMimeType());
        resp.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=" + instance.getFileName());
        ServletOutputStream out = resp.getOutputStream();
        try {
            InputStream is = resource.getResourceStream(instance);
            if (null != is) {
                byte[] buffer = new byte[2048];
                int length = -1;
                // Transfer the data
                while ((length = is.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                    out.write(buffer, 0, length);
                    out.flush();
                }
                is.close();
            }
        } catch (Throwable t) {
            logger.error("Error extracting protected resource", t);
            throw new ServletException("Error extracting protected resource", t);
        } finally {
            out.close();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you very much for answering! I have written the code again using everything you have posted and it works well for me!